# The first step to Speed Up using GPU

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, parallelization, cudalink

If we run the following code, mathematica kernel uses only CPU :

```
LinearOptimization[
  x + y, {x + 2 y >= 3, x >= -1, y >= -1}, {x, y}]
```

I want the following imaginary command `UseGPU` :

```
UseGPU[LinearOptimization][
  x + y, {x + 2 y >= 3, x >= -1, y >= -1}, {x, y}]
```

so that the result is the same, but this time kernel use GPU.

The above optimization problem was so simple, so that there is no  difference in `Timing`. (zero in both case)
But for similar problem with 20 variables and 20 conditions, `UseGPU` may be faster.

I've read some help documents about CUDAlink, Parallel computing, GPU computing, but it was difficult to understand.

I want a magic command like `UseGPU` that converts a certain built in function utilizing CPU to the same function utilizing GPU.

Or it is impossible, you can show a simple method that use GPU instead of CPU, that works for (a single time executed) `LinearOptimization`.

Comment: Yeah, it would be good to have such a magical command, right? Unfortunately, porting an algorithm to the GPU is extremely nontrivial. GPUs are "fast" only because they consist of many, many tiny workers (of which every single one is not _that_ fast ast all) that can work all concurrently on _independent_ tasks. So one needs quite different algorithms than on a CPU. And on top of that, the implementation have to be tuned very much to the actual hardware in use. The effort for developing them is not always worth the effort. So don't expect your magic "UseGPU" command to ever appear.

Comment: See also these posts why GPUs are not well suited for linear optimization: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012237852-Does-Gurobi-support-GPUs- and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70275285/8248900

Comment: To use a GPU in a meaningful way you need a problem that is inherently data-parallel, or if not, easily data-parallelizable. Linear programming is not such a type of problem. What you *can* do is to create your own "poor man's" *task-parallelization*, i. e. run LinearOptimization with the simplex method in one subkernel and with the interior point method in another subkernel, and conceivably other competing methods. Then the first method that comes back kills all the others, now you get the result of the fastest method, with all candidates competing.

Comment: However, that is task-parallelization, whereas GPUs are for data-parallelization. As @HenrikSchumacher included a Gurobi link I mention that this is what Bob Bixby and I had discussed in Nov 2002 in San Jose when he and his CPLEX team were integrating exactly this type of "parallel method competition" in CPLEX. But keep in mind, for the GPU you need data-parallel problems, not task-parallel problems.

Comment: [GPU Computing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GPUComputing.html)

Comment: Thank you, that was so helpful!